# Can't store date as start of the day in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, momentjs

I am storing a date in mongodb using mongose with the help of moment js.
I am creating the date object from a date string which is in the format `MM/DD/YYYY`.
below is how i assign the date

```
const startDate = momentTz(
    data.startDate,
    "MM/DD/YYYY",
    "Asia/Kolkata"
  ).startOf("day");
```

but ever time I assign this date object to the mongoose model while creating a document it is storing as `2022-11-30T18:30:00.000+00:00` ie, the time is being automatically set to `18:30`.
how can i set this to the start of the day.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
const startDate = momentTz(
    data.startDate,
    "MM/DD/YYYY",
    "Asia/Kolkata"
  ).startOf("day").toDate();
```

MongoDB stores Date values as UTC times - **always and only**. It is the client responsibility to display the date/time in local time zone and format.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores dates as [BSON](https://bsonspec.org/spec.html) type 9, which stores the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC.

18:30 UTC is midnight in Kolkata, so that date/time is correctly showing the start of the day 2022-11-31 IST.

It is up to the client program to convert from UTC to a different timezone if that is desired.